# Filtering a struct object containing a string and array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have a struct object holding a mapping of ports to their respective countries.

```
struct countryAndPorts {
    var country: String?
    var ports: [String]?
}
```

I have an array `var countryAndPortsArray = [countryAndPorts]()` that holds `countryAndPort` object for every country.

I also have an array  `var filteredArray = [countryAndPorts]()` which holds filtered `countryAndPortsArray` objects depending on the user's search query

I am filtering `countryAndPortsArray` with this function

```
func filteredContent(searchKey: String) {
    filteredArray = countryAndPortsArray.filter {
      !($0.ports?.filter{
           $0.range(of: searchKey, options: .caseInsensitive, range: 
           nil, locale: nil) != nil || 
           $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(searchKey) == .orderedSame
          }.isEmpty ?? true) || 
       $0.country?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchKey) ?? true
}
```

My problem is the result of `filteredArray` contains every port within the same country regardless the user's search key matches a particular port.

For example, if a user searches for "Paris", the `filteredArray` will contain every port in France. If a user searches "barcelona", the `filteredArray` will contain every port in Spain.

The desired result should only contain ports matching "barcelona" or "paris" and not every other port within the same country.

**UPDATE**

Use Case:

```
var france = countryAndPorts(country: "France", ports: 
["monaco","paris","ajaccio","lyon"])

var spain = countryAndPorts(country: "Spain", ports: ["barcelona", 
"madrid", "catalan"])

var countryAndPortsArray = [france,spain]
```

if i search `countryAndPortsArray` for barcelona, it returns `["barcelona", "madrid", "catalan"]`. However i would want it to only return `["barcelona"]`

here is my tableview delegates just incase it sheds more light to my question

```
extension SearchDealsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
    if let count = filteredArray[section].ports?.count {
        return count
    }
        return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
for: 
indexPath)

    if let port = filteredArray[indexPath.section].ports?
[indexPath.row] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = port
    }
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
    portsFromTextField.text = filteredArray[indexPath.section].ports?
    [indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"header")
    let tapSectionHeaderGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
    action: #selector(getCountryText(sender:)))
    tapSectionHeaderGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapSectionHeaderGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    header?.addGestureRecognizer(tapSectionHeaderGesture)

if header != nil {
    header?.textLabel?.textColor = THEME_COLOUR
    header?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    header?.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[section].country
}

return header
}

func getCountryText(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let country = sender.view as? UITableViewCell {
        portsFromTextField.text = country.textLabel?.text
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}
```

Comment: Could you provide small data example with expected result.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk updated

Answer (score 0):

I write solution but it is not perfect. But still it return expected result.

Firstly we could edit structure to fetch as preferred result.

```
struct countryAndPorts {
    var country: String?
    var ports: [String]?

    func getPort(_ withName: String) -> [String]? {
        return ports?.filter{$0.lowercased() == withName.lowercased()}
    }
}
```

Than out function to filter data. It is not perfect but it works it is possible to reduce amount of `flatMap` calls.

```
func fetch(port withName: String, from ports: [countryAndPorts]) -> [String]? {
    return ports.map{$0.getPort(withName)}.flatMap{$0}.filter{($0?.count)! > 0}.flatMap{$0}.first
}
```

Result:

```
fetch(port: "madrid", from: countryAndPortsArray) // ["madrid"]?
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Although i have managed to write a function that works perfectly, I will still test your answer and get back to you.